# Increase a number based on another number

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to increase a number in my database which I enter manually based on another number that is updated automatically from a device.

In my database I have a few columns, but the one that matters are
`cancelled_meter` `mec_in` `demult`.

``cancelled_meter`` is the column that is updated automatically

``mec_in`` is the column that is input manually

``demult`` is the column that is also updated automatically

These columns are all numbers (eg. `cancelled_meter` = 428080.00, `mec_in` = 2174827.00 and `demult` is usually 1, 100 or 1000.

Here's something I was trying to do in PHP:

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, cancelled_meter, total_drop, mec_in, mec_out, demult, val_pct 
            FROM machtest ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th>
                     <th>Coin IN Meter</th>
                     <th>Coin OUT Meter</th>
                     <th>Demultiplication</th>
                     <th>Pt Value</th>
                     <th>Total IN</th>
                     <th>Total OUT</th>
                  </tr>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $offset_in = $row["cancelled_meter"] - $row["mec_in"] * -1;
        $abbs_in = abs($offset_in);
        $round_in = abs($row["cancelled_meter"] / $row["demult"] + $abbs_in);
                
        $offset_out = $row["total_drop"] - $row["mec_out"] * -1;
        $abbs_out = abs($offset_out);
        $round_out = abs($row["total_drop"] / $row["demult"] + $abbs_out);
        
        echo "<tr>
                <td>"
                    .$row["id"]."</td>".
                "<td>"
                    .$row["cancelled_meter"]."</td>".
                "<td>"
                    .$row["total_drop"]."</td>".
                "<td>"
                    .$row["demult"]."</td>".
                "<td>"
                    .$row["val_pct"]."</td>".
                "<td>"
                    .$round_in."</td>".
                "<td>"
                    .round($row["total_drop"] / $row["demult"] + $abbs_out)."</td>
              <tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

This kind of works but I want to display `mec_in` which updates automatically when `cancelled_meter` changes and that only displays something else.

One more thing is that `mec_in` can be greater or lesser then  `cancelled_meter` that's why I need a positive result.
I was trying something like `mec_in` = `cancelled_meter` / `demult` + some offset that's between `cancelled_meter` and `mec_in`.

I'm trying to figure this out, but I'm a beginner, so if anyone has some suggestions I would very much appreciate it.

PS. I was trying to calculate this on the php file but in the MySQL is good too if anyone knows how.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: I want to display the column ``mec_in`` and it has to increase it's value based on ``cancelled_meter``. But it has to increase by a certain ammount, eg: ``cancelled_meter`` = 428080.00 then  ``mec_in`` = whatever I insert let's say 2174827.00. If ``cancelled_meter`` = 428090.00 then ``mec_in`` = 2174837.00 so on and so forth. This increase or decrease is based on the ``demult`` and ``cancelled_meter``.

Comment: So just calculate the new value of `mec_in` and stick it in a variable like you did for the other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what wase in my head, but after adding this `$total = abs($round_in - $row["offset_in"]);` worked just fine. I got `offset_in` column by doing `$round_in` - 
 `mec_in` and then `$round_in - $row["offset_in"]);` wich gives the desired result. Thank you for your input.